# How to Add A link in the product page

Tags: magento2, redirect, link

I want a to add a link the customer can click which will redirect them to another page(a product) on the site. How can i achieve this? Ideally I'd like the link to be in the section where customer chooses product option(See image)

[image: Product Options]

Answer (score 0):

You can create link.phtml file in the `Magento_Catalog` module.

```
<?php $product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php if($link = $product->getExternalLink()){ ?>
    <div class="link">
        <a href="<?= $link; ?>"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Link text')) ?></a>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

`

Call this file in Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="link" template="Magento_Catalog::link.phtml"/>
   </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Hope it will work.